# How to use ausmachen?

Tags: standard-german, grammar-identification

Ich hab‘ gehört, das macht echt was aus.

I heard ‘it really matters.

I know ausmachen meaning is to turn off and another possible meaning is to make up.
When I remove aus from above sentence, the meaning remains the same.
So, why aus is used in there?

Comment: See the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ausmachen#Verb) definition 4. I assume any good dictionary will list this meaning as well.

Answer (score 1):

"etwas ausmachen" can mean a lot of things. Here it means "to make a difference".

See https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/etwas%20ausmachen
or https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausmachen point 6 and 7

If you leave out the word "aus", as you suggested, you get:

> Ich hab‘ gehört, das macht echt was.

This is not a sentence I would use or that normally makes sense to me. Das macht was? Was macht es denn? It might be clear from context in some case, so the sentence isn't entirely wrong and can make sense in some situations, but then it has a different meaning than "... das macht echt was aus.".

You need the "aus" for it to mean "I heard this really makes a difference" or "I heard this really matters".

Comment: I think if you leave out the *was* as well then it makes a little sense, in a  kind of slangy, informal way. *Das macht echt.* Not something I'd expect to hear from someone over 30 though.